# Responsive navbar using flex is not collapsing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, navigationbar

I created a responsive navbar that contains a toggle menu using flex, but it does not collapse when in mobile view.

I also included a toggle btn provide by Font Awesome and integrated it into my project in the head of the html.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Here is the code for the navigation bar.

```
<div class="Navbar3">
       <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-brand">
       </div>
        <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-toggle">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>

      <nav class="Navbar__Items">
        <div class="Navbar__Link active">
          All
        </div>
        <div class="Navbar__Link">
          <a href="graphic.html">Design</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Navbar__Link">
          <a href="animation.html">Animation</a>
        </div>
      </nav>  
    </div>
```

Here is the css for the nav bar

```
  .Navbar3 {
  background-color: #2262AD;
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Navbar__Link {
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Navbar__Items {
  display: flex;

}
.Navbar__Link-toggle {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .Navbar__Items,
  .Navbar3 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
.Navbar__Items {
    display: none;
  }
.Navbar__Items--right {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
.Navbar__ToggleShow {
    display: flex;
  }
.Navbar__Link-toggle {
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: initial;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
   } 
}

.Navbar__Link:hover{
  color: black;
}

.active {
color: black;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here is some js for the toggle

```
function classToggle() {
          const navs = document.querySelectorAll('.Navbar__Items')

          navs.forEach(nav => nav.classList.toggle('Navbar__ToggleShow'));
        }
        document.querySelector('.Navbar__Link-toggle')
          .addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work just fine when I test it in the browser. If it is specifically mobile view that's not working try adding 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to your head. More at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). 
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I also tried the code in code pen and i got it to work, but in my index.html and style.css files, it still does not work for some reason...Heres the code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqapPM

Comment: I created a new code pen with my full code to see what the issue is.  Now it doesnt work.  It is something in the javascript.  I put in my full code for the html and css, but the js causes the issue.  Still looking at to how to fix it  CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMOmZj

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue.  It was cause by the last 2 lines of code in my js.  Commented them out and the navigation works fine!

```
function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      //dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      //captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
```